# Modify dynamically created product url in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, products, product-urls

I have enabled "**Use Categories Path for Product URLs**". Because of this, I get category path in product url. But when we search the product, it redirect to the product url that does not contain category path.

I want same url always whether from catalog page or from search.

Please tell me how to achieve this. I am going to have single category for single product always.

Thanks !

Comment: imagine that one product is related to 2 or more categories. Which one should be included in URL when user  use search?

Comment: Any one of the category should be picked up. My aim is to have just one url for each products. Url must consists of one of the categories it belongs.

Comment: Please help. I have not found solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that you will always have product in unique category. Then disable the 'Use Categories Path for product Urls' then perform the reindex.
Now you will have the same product url.

Comment: Yes I will always have product in unique category but I want Category path in product Urls for better seo.

Comment: Then you have to overwrite the **getUrl(){}**  function in file **Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Url**. Here you can change the **$requestPath = $product->getRequestPath();** If this path have category path included in it then you need not modify it. But if you have not category path in the requested path then you can append in it. Then all your product url will be with the category path at every page.